# JQuery click event firing off wrong element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a problem where the below code is being fired on the wrong element, the code below is inside the _create function of a jquery widget called tag, but when i click the x button as illustrated in the gif below, it removes the "goo" tag instead of "yoo" but i clicked on "yoo"

https://gyazo.com/c255d8c136624c235a3af0de4ee40fff

```
if(this.options.removable)
{

        this.removeButton = $("<span class='close glossy'>x</span>").appendTo(this.element);
        console.log(this.removeButton.parent().text());

        this.removeButton.click(function(e){
            alert(self.element.text());
            self._destroy();

            e.preventDefault();
        });
}
```

and this is the resulting html code for reference

[image of resulting html as displayed in the inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC14x.png)

Thanks in advance.

this is the full JS code for the widget

```
$.widget( "search.tagify", {

options: {
    followerCount: 30,
    description: 

    `a Javascript library, consider also adding the Javascript tag. jQuery is a
     popular cross-browser JavaScript library that facilitates
      Document Object Model (DOM) traversal, 
     event handling…,`,

    name: "tag name goes here",
    removable: false
},

_destroy: function()
{
    //Tips.remove(this.element);
    this.element.remove();
},

_create: function() {
    self = this;

    this.element
        .addClass( "tag" )
        .text( this.options.name )
        .protipSet({
            title: this.options.description,
            position: "bottom",
            size: "small",
            skin: "square",
            classes: "tag-tooltip",
        })

    if(this.options.removable)
    {

        this.removeButton = $("<span class='close glossy'>x</span>").appendTo(this.element);
        console.log(this.removeButton.parent().text());

        this.removeButton.click(function(e){
            alert(self.element.text());
            self._destroy();

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }

},

});
```

Comment: Can you post the html?

Comment: Where is `self` defined in your code?  It's not in the code you've provided where it should be `this`

Comment: Please post fiddle, it would be wrong to just look at code and give assumtions for you solution.

Comment: @freedomn-m I posted the full JS code for the widget. I defined self to be equal to 'this' in the outer scope.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please check the following code..

```
if(this.options.removable)
{

    this.removeButton = $("<span class='close glossy'>x</span>").appendTo(this.element);
    console.log(this.removeButton.parent().text());

    this.removeButton.click(function(e){
        alert(self.element.text());
        //here is the change you can access the targeted element like this as well
        $(e.target).parent('.tag').remove();

        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

I have made changes in the code please check, I have show the other mechanism for selecting the target

Comment: that's cool but i'm interested in why it's not working and why self.element is the wrong element.

Comment: Its selecting the class and its common with your last element and it removes the first element what ever it finds by using e.target it select the targeted element. Can you please mark answer as correct?